# Why git add -A add deletions

Tags: git

I am reading a book a here say:

There are three forms of the git add command:

• `git add foo.txt` adds a file named `foo.txt`
• `git add .` adds all new files and changed files, except deleted files
• `git add -A` adds everything, including deletions

If it seems nonsensical that the command `git add -A` “adds deletions,” don’t worry.

Could you give an example "`git add -A` adds everything, including deletions"?

Comment: It might be helpful to thing of "add" as "stage a change for commit". It adds something to the stage, like a file change, a file deletion or creation. It's not like adding the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

`git add -a` might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, an example.

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /usr/local/google/home/depp/test/.git/
$ touch b
$ git add b
$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   b
#
$ rm b
$ git add -A
$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

You can see that `git add -A` adds the deletion to the index.

Comment: What index? when you put the second git status I do not see anything referent to the b file

Comment: Yes, you don't see "b" in the second `git status` because it was deleted.  The index is a core Git concept, you may want to read about that.